# I am using ERPnext for our customers/clients. I want the users on the web portal to only see their orders and issues

Tags: doctype, erpnext, frappe

I am using ERPnext for our customers/clients. I want the users on the web portal to only see their orders and issues. I don't want web portal users to see other customers orders or issues. Can you help with how to go about doing this. I tried the ERPnext documentation, but I got no help.

I read up on the issues documentation. I tried using different roles and permission. I created a doctype to display the issues only. Can you please help with how I can implement this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.